# How do I export IIS7 app pool and its settings using Powershell to multiple servers

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7, powershell-4.0

What would be the best way to export and import Application Pool and its settings to number of other IIS 7 servers using PowerShell?
I've got already some good scripts built for the remote command executions on the IIS servers, but now have a task of quickly copy App Pools across large number of servers.

What would be the best approach towards doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this figured out.
The way I did it is:
Assign all properties of the app pool to the variable

```
$AppPoolProperties = Get-Item IIS:\\AppPools\APPPOOL | Select-Object *
```

then I export that variable to the CSV on the remote computer where I'm copying the app pool to.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Destination -ScriptBlock
{  
    $using:AppPoolProperties | Export-Csv -Path $using:csv -NoTypeInformation  
}
```

On remote host I load CSS into the variable and import each object into the newly created App Pool

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Destination -ScriptBlock  
{  
    Import-Module WebAdministration;  
    $Pools = (Import-Csv $using:csv);  
    New-Item -Path IIS:\AppPools\POOLNAME | Out-Null;  
    Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\POOLNAME -Name enable32BitAppOnWin64 -Value $pool.enable32BitAppOnWin64;  
    ......and so on adding other properties.....  
}
```